# My updated data does not reflect in even it is status 200

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to increase the score of a player by updating it. Here is the call.

```
const addPlayerScore = async (score, currentPlayer) => {
        try {
            const addScore = {
                score: score,
            };
            const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.patch(
                `/facilitator/add-score-player-team-one/${currentPlayer}`,
                addScore
            );
            console.log(data.message);
        } catch (error) {
            const { data } = error.response;
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    };
```

the **currentPlayer** takes the **id** of player. Which I passed into the params.

here is the request;

```
exports.addscoreplayerteamone = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { score } = req.body;

        const existLive = await LiveMatch.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                'teamOne.players._id': req.params.id,
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    $inc: {
                        'teamOne.players.$.scores': score,
                    },
                },
            },
            { new: true }
        );

        const addPlayerScore = await existLive.save();

        res
            .status(200)
            .send({ message: "Added the player's score", addPlayerScore });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'There was a problem adding a score',
        });
    }
};
```

here is the schema;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const liveSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        schedule: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
        teamOne: {
            teamName: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true,
                max: 50,
            },
            players: [
                {
                    name: {
                        type: String,
                        required: true,
                        trim: true,
                        max: 50,
                    },
                    jerseyNumber: {
                        type: String,
                        required: true,
                        trim: true,
                    },
                    scores: {
                        type: Number,
                        default: 0,
                        trim: true,
                    },
                    fouls: {
                        type: Number,
                        trim: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
            score: {
                type: Number,
                trim: true,
                default: 0,
            },
        },
        teamTwo: {
            teamName: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true,
                max: 50,
            },
            players: [
                {
                    name: {
                        type: String,
                        required: true,
                        trim: true,
                        max: 50,
                    },
                    jerseyNumber: {
                        type: String,
                        required: true,
                        trim: true,
                    },
                    scores: {
                        type: Number,
                        default: 0,
                        trim: true,
                    },
                    fouls: {
                        type: Number,
                        trim: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
            score: {
                type: Number,
                trim: true,
                default: 0,
            },
        },
        gameEvent: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: ['basketball', 'volleyball', 'soccer'],
        },
        winner: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
        },
        loser: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('live-match', liveSchema);
```

it returns status 200 but it does not increments the score of the player in the database nor being reflected in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const existLive = await LiveMatch.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
     'teamOne.players._id': req.params.id,
  },
  {
     $inc: { 'teamOne.players.scores': score }
  }, 
  { 
     new: true  
  }
);
```